# How can I create a function that iterates a list and simultaneously creates a new column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a function that returns multiple columns containing moving averages with different windows. But I get only one column returned.

This is what I've tried:

```
[3] data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
[4] data.head()
[4]     close
    0   126.70
    1   127.30
    2   127.38
    3   128.44
    4   128.77
[5] li = range(2,101)
[6] def builder(data):
        for n in li:
            data[n] = data.close.rolling(window=n).mean().shift()
            return data
[7] test = builder(data)
[8] test.head()
[8]     close   2
    0   126.70  NaN
    1   127.30  NaN
    2   127.38  127.00
    3   128.44  127.34
    4   128.77  127.91
```

Why doesn't my function return all the moving averages (2 to 100)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an indention problem, as your `return` is inside the loop, and the function returns after the first iteration. Change it to:

```
def builder(data):
    for n in li:
        data[n] = data.close.rolling(window=n).mean().shift()
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

check line "return data". Should not be in for-loop.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue!